# Query 1 table output same column twice with different filters showing what the other isn't

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to view the same column twice with different filters for each column.  Using SQL Server 08

Ex:  In the column I'm calling DPO, I want to only show job codes abc and xyz . The column labeled Work Needed needs to show all but job codes abc and xyz.

Below is part of my query minus some tables to shorten it up, which is why I'm pulling from 3 tables.

```
SELECT 

WkRoDesc.Job_Code AS [Work Needed], 
WkRoDesc.Job_Code AS [DPO]

FROM vhstock, WkInvReg, WkRoDesc

WHERE vhstock.no = WkInvReg.Stock_No AND WkInvReg.Ro_Number = WkRoDesc.Ro_Number
```

Comment: Can you show sample input data and how you expect the output to look?  It's not clear from your description.  Also, are you really working in MySQL, SQL Server, *and* SQLLite?

Comment: I cant show a picture as my rep on site isn't high enough yet, but I want to filter certain job codes to be displayed in DPO which there are 5 as of now and the other couple hundred jobs I want to show under the column work needed.  

Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?  Or were you wanting to do more with rows?

**EDIT:** Modified for SQL Server compatibility:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN WkRoDesc.Job_Code = 'abc' 
         OR WkRoDesc.Job_Code = 'xyz'
    THEN NULL ELSE WkRoDesc.Job_Code END AS WorkNeeded,
  CASE WHEN WkRoDesc.Job_Code = 'abc' 
         OR WkRoDesc.Job_Code = 'xyz'
    THEN WkRoDesc.Job_Code ELSE NULL END AS DPO
FROM vhstock, WkInvReg, WkRoDesc
WHERE vhstock.no = WkInvReg.Stock_No
  AND WkInvReg.Ro_Number = WkRoDesc.Ro_Number
```

Note: It almost sounded like you were looking for a `GROUP_CONCAT()` as well, but I thought I'd wait to be sure...

**EDIT2:** This uses some ugly XML processing in SQL Server to do something like MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT
  stuff((
    select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + j.Job_Code
    from WkRoDesc AS j
    where j.Ro_Number = WkInvReg.Ro_Number
      and NOT (j.Job_Code = 'abc' OR j.Job_Code = 'xyz')
    order by j.Job_Code
    for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS WorkNeeded,    
  stuff((
    select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + j.Job_Code
    from WkRoDesc AS j
    where j.Ro_Number = WkInvReg.Ro_Number
      and (j.Job_Code = 'abc' OR j.Job_Code = 'xyz')
    order by j.Job_Code
    for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS DPO
FROM vhstock, WkInvReg, WkRoDesc
WHERE vhstock.no = WkInvReg.Stock_No
  AND WkInvReg.Ro_Number = WkRoDesc.Ro_Number
GROUP BY WkInvReg.Ro_Number
```

Here's hoping it works on your system!

Comment: well I would yes eventually like to see the rows grouped being that their are multiple job codes that can be associated with the same piece of equipment.

Comment: The IF statement doesn't work I get and error but I can't see the error as I'm writing the SQL statement through a user interface and don't have access to Microsofs SQL server Management Studio

Comment: @user2752103 *Which* user interface? Please fix the question's tags so that we know which database you are actually using.

Comment: @user2752103 You're probably using SQL Server?  MySQL `IF` would need to be converted to SQL Server `IIF` or a `CASE` statement.

Comment: I am using SQL server 08 r2 for database and the user interface is from a company called Foresight Intelligence.  I know the SQL server is making a connection to another database but I do not know what is running that DB as it is not controlled by our company, but by the franchise.

Comment: @user2752103 `Select @@version as x` is SQL Server, `SELECT VERSION()` is MySQL.  If neither of those works, we can conjecture about SQLite...  If you can't run those, then it probably shouldn't matter as SQL Server is proxying and pretty much responsible.

Comment: Thank you this does work.  Is there a way to group them if an stock # has more then one associated with it?

Comment: @user2752103 see the additional query for a way to put extra column values into a comma delimited string.  (kinda messy, but should hopefully work)

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN WkRoDesc.Job_Code in ('abc','xyz') then NULL ELSE WkRoDesc.Job_Code END AS [Work Needed], 
CASE WHEN WkRoDesc.Job_Code in ('abc','xyz') then WkRoDesc.Job_Code ELSE NULL END AS [DPO]
FROM vhstock, WkInvReg, WkRoDesc
WHERE vhstock.no = WkInvReg.Stock_No AND WkInvReg.Ro_Number = WkRoDesc.Ro_Number
```

Comment: Out of curiosity what DB supports `IN` but not `IF()`?  SQLite?

Comment: Thank you this works-- if some can mark it I cant as this is a new account till my rep hits 15

Comment: @ebyrob Although SQL server supports ´IF´ I'm pretty sure it is only for program flow, not for conditional selecting in a query for that you should use ´CASE´

Comment: @Hedinn I know SQL Server doesn't use `IF()` (it does use `IIF()`).  Huh, when I ran that query before (2008 R2) it didn't seem to be working due to `IN`.  I guess SQL Server does support it.

Comment: @ebyrob `IIF` isn't supported until SQL SERVER 2012, not in 2008 R2, but `in` has been supported from at least 2005

Comment: @Hedinn aha! That's it!  I think I last used SQL Server 2003 in any kind of production environment.  (So one little error code had me assuming it just wasn't there)